We are trying to integrate Telerik Reports in Angular client with Rest API done in .Net Core
We are trying to integrate Telerik Reports in Angular client with Rest API done in .Net Core.
1).In .Net Core, REST API Project we have installed two nuget packages Telerik.Reporting.Trial AND Telerik.Reporting.Services.AspNetCore.Trial
For API Project Code Snippet is below :
TelerikReportController ,
` [ApiController]
[Route("api/TelerikReports")]
public class TelerikReportController : ReportsControllerBase
{
public TelerikReportController(IReportServiceConfiguration reportServiceConfiguration) : base(reportServiceConfiguration)
{
  }

}`
And Configuration of TelerikReports in Program.cs file is as below :
var reportsPath = Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Reports"); builder.Services.AddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp => new ReportServiceConfiguration { HostAppId = "MyApp", Storage = new FileStorage(), ReportSourceResolver = new TypeReportSourceResolver() .AddFallbackResolver( new UriReportSourceResolver(reportsPath)) });
I have put up few sample reports under the folder "Reports" in project hierarchy.
2). For Angular client , We have add following code to the component designer.component.html code is below :
<div id="webReportDesigner"><div>
we are trying to call .NET API in designer.component.ts , file is as below :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-designer',
  templateUrl: './designer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./designer.component.css']
})
export class DesignerComponent {
  designer: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.designer = $("#webReportDesigner").telerik_WebReportDesigner({
      serviceUrl: "http://localhost:7000/api/TelerikReports/",(I have put up my REST API localhost url here)
      report: "~/Reports/Test.trdp"
    }).data("telerik_WebDesigner");
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    var webReportDesignerTheme = $("link[href*='ext_styles/webReportDesignerTheme']");
    var webReportDesigner = $("link[href*='styles/webReportDesigner']");
    var fonticons = $("link[href*='font/fonticons']");  
    if (webReportDesignerTheme.length > 1) {
      webReportDesignerTheme.last().remove();
    }
    if (webReportDesigner.length > 1) {
      webReportDesigner.last().remove();
    }
    if (fonticons.length > 1) {
      fonticons.last().remove();
    }
  }
}

My REST API project is running at http://localhost:7000 and when I start Angular application, I get following errors (which I understand because jquery is not getting loaded properly).
Based on above code, can anyone suggest what is missing to load Jquery properly so that designer can be loaded in angular client application?
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/v8MzRb9o.png)
